# FreeNAS 8.2.x - IDE vmware drive detected as multipath and causing errors

Tags: virtual-machine, freenas, raid-z

First of all I had FreeNAS 7 running as dedicated on HP Microserver, then upgraded to 8 upgrading my pool as well (4x1TB RaidZ)

Since I upgraded to FreeNAS 8 I had this message popping up. it meant but today it just bugged me to death and I wanted to fix it.

> The following multipaths are not optimal: disk1

I looked around and found what that if FreeNAS finds a drive that is compatible with multipath it will add it in..for SAS drives? I do not use that just normal SATA.

Then I got annoyed with some missing features in FreeNAS and I installed windows server - put in 8GB RAM - Made a virtual machine with 4GB dedicated to FreeNAS. So I got Windows for all my windows notebooks at home and a great NAS solution .. all in one. The error is still there. All drives are the same running in IDE emulation (because SCSI is not fully supported in FreeNAS 8.2.x for VMware ... yet)

Please look at the screenshots - I have no idea what it means and it is confusing me. Is it OK or DEGRADED? Its telling me both.. arrrr-

Volume status 
[image]

Multipath screen
[image]

[image]

It says that the zpool is all OK- but it seems like one of the drives does not spin up anymore- it is the loudest one and needs replacing some time soon because it is annoying.. So I cannot tell if my RaidZ is healthy or not. How the can I get rid of that error and double check my RaidZ is stable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that one of the hard drives has a feature built into it that the FreeBSD system can utilize. It will work as normal but FreeNAS removes it from the ATA list and mkaes it look as if something is broken.

Your pool is still synchronised and there is no problem. Nothing to worry about.